# Haskell: translating to a Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

In an effort to understand monads better, I'm attempting to write my own. I'm starting with some non-monadic code, and could use some help translating it into a monad.

Basic idea for this contrived example: for each integer result of a computation, I'd like to track if that integer is even or odd. For example, in `4 + 5 = 9`, we might return `(9, Odd)`.

I'd like to be able to chain/compose the calculations with `>>=`. For example:

```
return 1 >>= (+2) >>= (+5) >>= (+7) =result=> (15, Odd)
```

Right now, I have the following non-monadic code:

```
data Quality = Odd | Even deriving Show

qual :: Integer -> Quality
qual x = case odd x of
             True -> Odd
             _ -> Even

type Qualifier = (Integer, Quality)

mkQ :: Integer -> Qualifier
mkQ x = (x, qual x)

plusQ :: Qualifier -> Qualifier -> Qualifier
plusQ (x, _) (y, _) = (x+y, qual (x+y))

chain = plusQ (mkQ 7) . plusQ (mkQ 5) . plusQ (mkQ 2)
```

What are some ways I can translate the above code into a monad? What are some of the patterns I should look for, and what are common translation patterns for them?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not easily admit a monadic translation. Monads are parameterized by a type, and make sense for any type. Yor computation only makes sense for intrgers.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to model state transformations / actions, where your state in this case is the `Quality`. You'll want to look at the [**State Monad**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more), where your state monad is parameterized by `Quality` and your operations `(+1)` would turn into state actions.

Comment: @n.m. Good point, and one that I was beginning to see and wonder about. What might be a better example of a simple, generic process that would fit an exercise like this?

Comment: @weirdcanada I was wondering about either using State or Writer monads for this... Writer because the Even/Odd aspect seemed almost like logging. But I was really trying to write my own monad in order to understand the inner and outer workings of monads better. Any ideas?

Comment: One simple monad represents computations that may end in an error. Described everywhere, but it's still entertaining to come up with your own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of learning from this one. Many thanks to the commentors and answers for your time and guidance!

To summarize:

**Solution**: As @n.m. and others commented, there isn't a good monad translation for this example because my original model isn't type-generic. Monads are best for type-generic computation patterns. Good examples given include the `Maybe` monad for computations which may fail, and `State` monad for storing and carrying along accessory state information through a computation chain.

As an **alternate solution**, @GabrielGonzalez offered a great solution using type instancing. This keeps the inherent type-specificity of my original model, but broadens its interface to support more of the `Num` type class interface and clean up the functional interactions.

**Next steps**: As @weirdcanada and others recommended, I think I'll go play with the `State` monad and see how I can apply it to this particular example. Then I may try my hand at a custom definition of Maybe as @n.m. recommended.

Again, many thanks to those who commented and responded!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you actually want is a `Num` instance for `Qualified`:

```
data Qualified = Qualified { isEven :: Bool, value :: Integer }

instance Num Qualified where
    (Qualified e1 n1) + (Qualified e2 n2) = Qualified e (n1 + n2)
      where
        e = (e1 && e2) || (not e1 && not e2)

    (Qualified e1 n1) * (Qualified e2 n2) = Qualified (e1 || e2) (n1 * n2)

    abs (Qualified e n) = Qualified e (abs n)

    signum (Qualified e n) = Qualified e (signum n)

    fromInteger n = Qualified (even n) n
```

This lets you manipulate `Qualified` numbers directly using math operators:

```
>>> let a = fromInteger 3 :: Qualified
>>> let b = fromInteger 4 :: Qualified
>>> a
Qualified {isEven = False, value = 3}
>>> b
Qualified {isEven = True, value = 4}
>>> a + b
Qualified {isEven = False, value = 7}
>>> a * b
Qualified {isEven = True, value = 12}
```

Comment: OP probably wants a `Num` instance, but I think the broader goal is that the OP wants to learn and understand monads.

Comment: I worry that teaching monads in the context of this specific problem would do more harm than good.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez good concern, and concern acknowledged. What might be a better simple type of monad one could write from scratch to get a better sense of monads?

Comment: The `State` monad is pretty simple, if you want to learn about monads, define your own `State` monad and then maybe try to write your own parser using your new monad.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Agreed.